# How to Update a Task (change User Story) using Rally API?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, rally

So I am trying to update a Task and change the User Story it belongs to.  This is what i am trying..

```
var toUpdate = new DynamicJsonObject();

// the new User Story
toUpdate["WorkProduct"] = "/hierarchicalrequirement/4567890123";

// the ObjectID of the Task
long oid = 45678912445; 

OperationResult result = _restApi.Update("task", oid, toUpdate);
```

But getting this error: `System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String]`

Comment: I put together a little example to reproduce what you are doing and it worked just fine.  Do you have the full stack trace of your error?  What version of the Rally REST API for .NET are you using?  (The most recent version is 1.04)

Comment: Hey Kyle, that error is from result.Errors of the OperationResult, so not sure how to get more information

Comment: It must have been some string error that i overlooked.  It is working now.  thanks for checking!

Comment: @robnardo, Post what you did to fix it and accept it as the answer.

Comment: This was a defect that has been fixed in versions 1.06 of the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I got to work prior to any bug fixes reported by Kyle Morse..

```
public string ProxyUpdateTask(Task myTask, string strWorkProduct)
    {

        var message = @"<span style=""color:green;"">SUCCESS</span>";
        const string errPrefix = @"<span style=""color:red;"">ERROR</span>";

        var toUpdate = new DynamicJsonObject();

        long oid;
        Int64.TryParse(myTask.ObjectId, out oid);

        toUpdate["WorkProduct"] = String.Format("/hierarchicalrequirement/{0}", myTask.UserStoryId);


        try
        {
            var result = _restApi.Update("task", oid, toUpdate);
            if (!result.Success) 
                message = String.Format(@" {2} updating (ObjectID={0}) failed. {1}", myTask.ObjectId, result.Errors, errPrefix);
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            message = String.Format(" {0} - {1}", errPrefix, ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            message = String.Format(" {0} - {1}", errPrefix, ex.Message);
        }

        return message;

    }
```